# Callback to be used when the element (div) is visible and not visible in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I need to find a way to get two callbacks, which are trigged when the div/img is visible on the screen and when it is not longer visible. What Can I use on Angular?

```
<div (onVisibleOnScreen)="doSomething1()" (onDisappearOnScreen)="doSomething2()">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use behavior subject to control both state and visibility of the DIV element.
Then invoke a function depending on his state.

Check this working example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4ws3hq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `HostListener` on the window scroll event. At the view initialization and each time the user scroll, you compute if your div/img is on screen with a `ViewChild` and the `window`.

```js
@HostListener("window:scroll", [])
onWindowScroll() {
  this.onScroll();
}

@ViewChild("myElement") myElement: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>;

public onScroll(): void {
  const windowYVisibility = {
    min: window.pageYOffset,
    max: window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight
  };

  const myElementYVisibility = {
    min: this.myElement.nativeElement.offsetTop,
    max:
      this.myElement.nativeElement.offsetTop +
      this.myElement.nativeElement.offsetHeight
  };

  const isElementVisible =
    (windowYVisibility.max > myElementYVisibility.min &&
      windowYVisibility.min < myElementYVisibility.min) ||
    (windowYVisibility.min < myElementYVisibility.max &&
      windowYVisibility.max > myElementYVisibility.max);
}
```

[Here is a working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2b8zfd?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thank you! Suppose I've a list of div, within a div, how Can I handle this situation?

Comment: You can use a ViewChildren instead of a ViewChild, in order to call the method on each children.
Depending on your specs, if you want to check if all of them are on screen you can use this.myElements.toArray().every(this.isOnScreen). And if you want to check if at least one is on screen you can use this.myElements.toArray().some(this.isOnScreen).
ps: we suppose that the method isOnScreen return a boolean